# How do fix a garage door opener that only briefly hums when activated?

Tags: garage-door-opener

I have a Lift Master garage door opener that is a quarter of a century old.  Several years ago, I serviced the motor by replacing a worn out cog that appears to be constructed from some plastic material; I was able to get a repair kit on Amazon.

Now, the same garage door opener is exhibiting this odd behavior.  When activated, it makes a brief electronic hum for only about one second.  I know that the trolley and chain and set up correctly.  I opened the dust-cover from the motor and noticed that the electronic hum comes from inside the motor somewhere, but there is no movement at all.  I suspect that perhaps there is a solenoid that has failed because none of the moving parts activate.

If it makes any difference, the garage door moves freely up and down with the pull-string in spite of the motor malfunctioning.

What can I check to try and diagnose the problem?

Comment: Remove, recycle, install new one, with a new warranty and new circuit boards and parts. It's VERY easy to head down the road of spending more to fix an old opener than it costs to buy a new one, and in most cases the parts are neither returnable nor warrantied. Malfunctions can injure or kill you. I have repaired a relatively new one when I was pretty sure of the cause and willing to gamble half the price of a new one on the part, but 25 years old - I'd replace it, without a doubt.

Comment: Are there any safety sensors (photoeyes) on this opener?

Comment: Sounds like the large capacitor on the  motor has failed. Look if capacitor is swollen. Testing is really dangerous.....somehow the motor has to be pushed (in the right direction) when turned on. Best just replace.